# If $G$ is a Lie group, is $[G,G]$ always Lie subgroup

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

Let $G$ be a connected Lie group, $[G,G]$ its derived subgroup (i.e. subgroup generated by commutators of elements in $G$).  Here is my question:

Is $[G,G]$ always a Lie subgroup, meaning a does it have the structure of a Lie group such that the inclusion map $[G,G]\rightarrow G$ is an immersion? (i.e. I do not require $[G,G]$ to be a submanifold with respect to the induced topology)  If so, why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One shows this as follows, for a connected simply connected Lie group $G$.

- Let $g$ be the Lie algebra of $G$ and $g'$ it derived Lie algebra, which is an ideal in $g$. Then $g/g'$ is an abelian Lie algebra, corresponding to an abelian, connected simply connected Lie group $H$. The map $g\to g/g'$ corresponds to a morphism of groups $f:G\to H$. Since $H$ is abelian, the derived subgroup $G'$ of $G$ is contained in the kernel $K$ of $f$. The Lie algebra of $K$ is $g'$: this follows from it construction. Moeover, the group $K$ is connected:
- Next, one shows that a path-connected neigborhood of $1$ in $K$ is contained in $G'$. if $x$ and $y$ are in $g$, then then the curve $t\mapsto [\exp(\sqrt t x),\exp(\sqrt ty)]$ takes values in $G'$ and its tangent vector at $0$ is $[x,y]$ (one has to extend the curve to a neighborhood of zero, this formula only works for positive $t$); as commutator of elements of $g$ generate the Lie algebra of $K$, what we want follows. Using this we see that in act $G'$ and $K$ coincide.

In all, this is not a trivial at all.

Comment: I think I understand this argument except the last line, "...as commutator of elements of $g'$ generate the Lie algebra of $K$, what we want follows".
Why is this good enough?  What if $g'$ only has these paths with tangent vectors giving $\mathfrak{g}'$ but doesn't contain a neighborhood of $K$ near the identity?

Comment: There is a neighborhood the identity in $K$ is entirely composed of elements which are exponentials of elements in its Lie algebra.

Comment: Yes, but how do we know the paths in $g'$ include these exponential paths?  What if, for instance, none of the paths tangent to $X\in\mathfrak{g}$ in $g'$ intersect the exponential $exp(tX)$ except at $e$?

Comment: I do not understand what you wrote.

Comment: I don't understand why the fact about exponentials you wrote helps us unless we know, for instance, that all the exponentials are contained in $g'$ (at least in a some neighborhood of $e$).

Comment: Exponentials **cannot** be in $g'$: they are in the group, not the Lie algebra. I am sorry but I cannot make sense of your comments :(

Comment: You can find the complete argument in *Lie Groups and Lie Algebras I* by V.V. Gorbatsevich and E.B. Vinberg.

Comment: Oh sorry, I meant to write $G'$ that whole time!

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is always a Lie group in the sense that it has the structure of a Lie group for which the inclusion map is an immersion.

More generally:

> **Theorem** (Greenberg) When $H, K \subset G$ are Lie subgroups, their commutator subgroup $[H, K]$ is a Lie subgroup. Its Lie algebra is the smallest subalgebra of $\mathfrak g$ containing $[\mathfrak h, \mathfrak k]$ that is invariant under $\operatorname{Ad}_H$ and $\operatorname{Ad}_K$.

- L. Greenberg, *Commutator groups and algebras.* Journal of Research of the National Bureau of Standards — B. Mathematical Sciences. Vol. 73B, No.3, July–September 1969, pp. 247–249. https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/jres/73B/jresv73Bn3p247_A1b.pdf

In particular, $[G, G]$ is a Lie subgroup with Lie algebra $[\mathfrak g, \mathfrak g]$.

Answer (score -1):

If $G$ is simply connected, then $[G,G]$ does have the structure of a Lie group. The fact that it is a subgroup of the given Lie group $G$ is trivial. The reason that it is, in fact, a Lie subgroup is a consequence of being topologically closed via the Closed subgroup theorem.

Comment: What you wrote does not prove anything, as far as I can tell.

Comment: I'm confused by this answer as well.  I'm not sure why it's imposed by the regularity of multiplication and inversion.  Perhaps you could elaborate?

Comment: Apparently you need that $G$ is simply connected to ensure that it is closed (and hence Cartan's theorem, aka Closed subgroup theorem is applicable; see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed_subgroup_theorem) Sourse: 2nd answer here: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/90216/commutator-of-closed-subgroups

Comment: Thanks.  I think I get this case.  I'm interested in what can be said in general, though.

Comment: That the commutator subgroup is closed is precisely the  non-trivial fact that has to be proved here, and in fact depends on simply-connectedness.

Comment: It's not closed in general: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/90216/commutator-of-closed-subgroups

Comment: I'm curious about if it's at least a Lie subgroup, but not necessarily closed.  Although I think this is also true for compact groups.

Comment: @freeRmodule. Pass to the universal cover.

Comment: Ah, great, thanks!